# Remove ANSI Escape codes from logging message to file

Tags: python, logging, ansi-escape, python-logging

I've written a script that does something and logs its actions to

1. the console and
2. a file
   with the python module logging.

In the console, I want coloured output, which is why I use ANSI Escape Codes. But I do not want them to appear in my logfile, since they make it barely readable.
These are the codes I use:

```
class colors:
    BLACK = "\u001b[30m"
    RED = "\u001b[31m"
    GREEN = "\u001b[32m"
    YELLOW = "\u001b[33m"
    BLUE = "\u001b[34m"
    MAGENTA = "\u001b[35m"
    CYAN = "\u001b[36m"
    WHITE = "\u001b[37m"
    BOLD = "\u001B[1m"
    RESET = "\u001b[0m"
```

This is the class I use to remove the codes from the record.msg for the file logging handler, the console logger uses a different class.

```
class FileLogFormat(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if any(ANSI in record.msg for ANSI in ANSI_CODES):
            for ANSI in ANSI_CODES:
                record.msg = record.msg.replace(ANSI, "")
        log_fmt = FFORMATS[record.levelno]
        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=log_fmt, style="{", datefmt=DATE_FORMAT)  # set f string formatting style
        return formatter.format(record)
```

This is how a logged message looks like:

```
logger.warning(f"{colors.RED}Hi this is a {colors.GREEN} test msg")
```

This works, but using a for loop feels very un-pythonic to me, which tells me that I am not understanding how exactly the logging module's format function works.

Could someone explain to me a more pythonic way of removing the ANSI escape codes?

Comment: You may be interested in the [logging handler](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html) provided by the [`rich` module](https://rich.readthedocs.io).